# ligtable in metafont

Tags: fonts, ligatures, metafont

I would like to combine three characters, should they appear consecutively, and replace the three with a single glyph (which is pre-defined). Is it possible to use ligtable to do it in a metafont file ?

Comment: I don't know much about MetaFont. How are the TFM files produced? Are they generated from the `.mf` source? Because I'm guessing that ligatures must end up in the TFM files, in the same way they do for type1 fonts. In that case, the ligatures are not defined as part of the font itself - that information has to be added when creating them. But fonts designed for TeX might be different.

Comment: Conceptually, what you need is this: suppose abc should become &, then you need 2 slots in your encoding to be free: one you put & into and the other you put @ into. Then you define two ligatures: the first: ab -> @; the second @c -> &. @ might just be a combination of a and b but it must be defined as its own character, so it needs a slot in the encoding. Take a look at the way the ligature ffl is defined. The only difference is that ff may not be a 'real' ligature glyph-wise in your case, even though it must be a ligature to TeX.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward to do with type1 fonts. So I assume it is the same process for source fonts.

Comment: Hi cfr, Thanks for the reply. Your method works but takes up too much space. The glyph table is already almost full and I need many such three-combos (which are not arbitrary, the middle character is the same). So if there were a way of directly combining three without going through the intermediate step, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Ligatures only apply to two characters at a time and a two character ligature should point to a character that exists in the font. See section 13 in the documentation of PLtoTF (`texdoc pltotf`, page 308).

Comment: You can't do that. It is not the way ligatures work. That's why I made the point about needing the additional slot: this is, indeed, a constraint on designing suitable TeX support for fonts (type1, metafont etc.). That's just how it is. For a 3 character ligature, the first 2 must be a ligature in their own right. That can be just first+second rather than a different glyph, but it has to occupy a slot. You can only look at two consecutive characters at a time. The same issue occurs only more so when supporting certain kinds of fancy swashes where end-of-word needs a slot, for example.

Comment: Can you split the font into 2? That's the other option, of course. Even if you have to repeat some characters in both. Having no idea what you're doing, I have no idea what would work. But this is, I think, the only remaining possibility using traditional TeX fonts. There is just the limit of 256 slots per encoding and you can't get away from it. If you can work with something like opentype instead, then XeTeX/LuaTeX free you from this constraint, of course. But I assume those are not options.